# carrierwave uploader uploads file, but still serves up default_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave in a rails 3 application to upload and store a file from a remote source in my server's file system. I've got a setup that's totally standard, with an uploader mounted on the model that the image is associated with.

It works perfectly 99.9% of the time, but every 600th graph or so I run into an issue where the app persistently fails to serve the stored image. If I check on the filesystem, the graph image has been uploaded and stored in the correct location, with the correct file permissions and everything, but rails is totally unaware of it and continues to serve the default graph image for that instance.

In other words a graph with id 123 has it's image stored at /uploads/graphs/123/graph.png ... the correct image is there but as far as rails is concerned it has no image stored. All the other graph images still work fine, but I can't get rails aware of the image stored for 123. Removing and re-storing the image doesn't work. Manually removing the image and re-uploading doesn't work. I'm totally lost. The graph instance is valid, no errors in the logs when I save.

for example, in the console:

```
g = Goal.find_by_id("123")
g.remote_graph_url = "http://image.source/url.png"
> "http://image.source/url.png"
g.save
> true
g.graph?
> false
g.graph_url >> /default/image.png
```

here's the relevant code:

```
class GraphUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "../uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  def default_url
    "/images/" + [version_name, "default_large_graph.png"].compact.join('_')
  end
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
  def filename
    "graph.png" if original_filename
  end
end

class Graph 
  mount_uploader :graph, GraphUploader
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could just reply...

So you are saving uploads outside of the public directory? Try removing the "../" before images, if that wasn't your intention.

Comment: yeah, they're storing where I want them. And again, it's only 1/600 things it fails on.. so weird!

Comment: Hmm... You are using png as filename, without a process of converting gifs/jpegs to pngs...... By chance could that be why?

Comment: i'm using png for the filename because the images are generated as pngs. Again, it works for 99.9% of images uploaded, but every once in a blue moon (maybe 8 out of 8200) it fails for a particular goal and persistently won't update the model, but keeps serving the default image. I still haven't resolved it yet :-)